# What is the best way to implement distributed locks in Redis, for Kotlin service and Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, lettuce, redisson

I am working on a scenario where i want to implement distributed redis lock in my service. The service is built in Kotlin and Spring Boot (i am new to both). The requirement is to acquire lock in one API and release in another API. There are some libraries like jedis, lettuce and redisson, which are used to implement redis client.

Which one is best suited in this scenario? I know jedis does not have async capability, so most probably its either lettuce or redisson.

Which has better performance?

Can anyone please suggest which one should i move forward? some implementation example would really helpful.